# When to hit API vs Django Built-in Functions

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a website/native app combo built using django. To support the native app, I built an api backend using django-rest-framework. I read in multiple sources that this was [a good idea](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-better-to-use-REST-API-to-have-one-backend-for-website-and-mobile-apps) Now, if I want to interact with my database, I seem to have too many options and I'm wondering what's industry best practice.

For example, if I want to surface a simple form to update a User, based on my past django experience, I would lean toward creating an UpdateView. However, I'm now wondering if I should instead build a form that posts to my User API endpoint via AJAX. From what I've read, it appears the second option would be more aligned with an API-first approach.

However, this would also require that I do more upfront work in effectively rebuilding a lot of built-in django functionality. Also, it seems to me that this is less efficient, as pages that before involved a single HTTP request now will require multiple. Is there any validity to optimization concerns around multiple HTTP requests per page? Is there an upper bound I should be wary of (say for example if I'm allowing a user to update/insert dozens of records on a single page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, it seems to me that this is less efficient, as pages that before
>   involved a single HTTP request now will require multiple.

Welcome to the single page application world :)

You are totally correct, this is a problem that plagues many SPA style websites. Doing several API calls would always cause a higher upfront loading time for your website/application when compared to a single HTTP call that returns a server-rendered HTML page.

There is nothing wrong with building a "classic" website, and while following an "API first" has its merits it does not invalidate other approaches for building websites. Building a single page application will inevitably make you rewrite many things that Django gives you for free, like forms or i18n. On the other hand, having a clean separation of frontend and backend makes it easier to manage and hire different people working on different parts of the application.

It's a bit hard to give you a straight answer without knowing exactly what you are trying to build. But I can give you some suggestions based on my experience.

## Tailor you API to your frontend.

Developers seem to love building beautiful REST APIs: every resource with its own endpoint, proper HTTP responses, PUT, POST, DELETES, etc. But that's all useless if your frontend needs to do 20 requests in order to submit a single form. Be pragmatic. Build an endpoint for *your* frontend that does everything it needs in a single HTTP call. That's not easier but also safer, you can do everything in a single database transaction and rollback if an error happens.

## Pre-warm your frontend

It's possible that some of your endpoints never or very rarely change. You might have a "country" endpoint that returns a list of countries to display in a dropdown, or maybe your user has a list of contacts that don't change that often. You can put all that information in a single endpoint and make your front-end load it as soon as it opens the page.

## Return pre-rendered HTMLs in some endpoints.

I did this in the past and some people wanted to kill me for this :) We had a dynamic form that changed according to some configuration in the backend. Doing this is a "pure API" way would require building an endpoint only to return this configuration, and then dynamically building the form in the front-end. Not only that we also had to match the form validation with the backend Model validation. That's a lot of wasted time in my opinion. DRF has a nice trick for that, you can actually tell DRF to render a serializer as an HTML form, you can then customize the form template and make it return an Angular or React template if you wish.

## GraphQL

GraphQL as kinda built to solve problems like this, but I never built a GraphQL backend in Django, so I can't give much advice on that.